# How do I audit database changes with the Play Framework?

Tags: sql, hibernate, scala, playframework, hibernate-envers

I'm learning the Play Framework... and I'm wondering how to implement an auditing mechanism to track DB operations (add, modify, delete). For instance, I'd expect something very similar to Hibernate where audit tables are created automatically... Does anybody know if there is a good document that explains how to audit database changes with the Play Framework? I'm using the Play! 2.0 and PostgreSQL 9.1.

Any help would be really appreciated ;-)

Comment: If you even don't specify Play's version and selected ORM, I can ensure you, that nobdy give you the correct answer.

Comment: OK, I've just updated my post with version information.

Comment: @j3d I am not aware of what Hibernate does. But as a solution (if there's no better solution) you could try to start a transaction and add your data and the executed operation in another table.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using an ORM (you didn't specify)

In that case, you should take into account that anorm is not a full fledged orm (ANti ORM, I guess that's where it's name come from) it's just a tiny and practical wrapper around plain jdbc.

So I think you should implement some kind of logging by yourself, as Andrew suggested.

You could also try hacking into anorm itself, or come up with something playing with function compositions.

Comment: Yes, I'm using anorm... but I think I should give a look at Slick. Let me try it and then I'll come back with more info.